# Why does Telegram roll its own crypto?

Tags: encryption, symmetric

Telegram recently updated its symmetric-key encryption scheme [MTProto](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/description), which seems to fix some known vulnerabilities. Nevertheless, I still do not understand why they roll their own crypto. What properties/advantages do they gain from their homemade MTProto encryption scheme beyond those already provided by the standard key derivation and authenticated encryption schemes?

Comment: Why don't ask you Telegram directly?

Comment: Are you referring to  AES' IGE mode?

Comment: @PaulUszak Yes, I think the current MTProto scheme is still using AES IGE, but it also has key derivation and message authentication components. So, I am referring to the whole MTProto encryption scheme vs authenticated encryption scheme. But we can assume the DH result has been properly shared between the end users.

Comment: @mentallurg Thanks for reminding me of this option. I just sent an email to their security feedback, but I doubt getting any meaningful response.

Comment: I don't *know* why, but probably a combination of naivete, ignorance and arrogance.  Everything I've read says that its crypto is terrible.

Comment: @ShanChen Did you ever receive a reply to your email?

Comment: @EllaRose No. I doubt they would reply whatsoever. It seems that their MTProto scheme is not designed by cryptographers and not surprisingly had suffered from several bugs. Although some of them are fixed, their scheme is still not provably secure.

Comment: The "why" is always hard to answer. They do seem to be using standard primitives (although you can argue that IGE modes are not *that* standard) and try and implement their own protocol. That's possibly not as bad as inventing your own *primitives (algorithms)* such as variants of RSA or AES but it leaves enough room for mistakes - as their implementation clearly seems to show, yes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the only way to answer this question is from input by the Telegram team - the information doesn't seem to be publicly available. If anybody can get them to answer then please flag this question for reopening...

Comment: @Swashbuckler what have you read?